# Adding a border around the first row in a table (and other styling)?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the first row of a table, which is supposed to serve as a heading-row. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get a visible border around this row.

I went about this by trying to use the first:child pseudo class. I managed to successfully get a background gradient added to this row. The code for that looks like...

```
tr:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(116, 195, 80);
    -webkit-background:linear-gradient(rgb(116, 195, 80), rgb(160, 219, 132));
```

So now I'm trying to add a border around this row... And none of my code seems to really work. What's making it even more obnoxious for me is the fact that I have plenty of working border code in other parts of this css file... And none of it seems to give a visible border for this row. I actually don't want the border to span for the entire row. I am okay with the border simply going around each column/element within the row.

Right now my code is....

```
border-style: groove;
border-color: blue;
border-height: 5px;
border-radius: 4px;
```

There must be something I'm not understanding about table styling...
I am not allowed to alter the original html5 file.
Here is an example table I'm trying to imitate.

[image: Example table heading]

Comment: perhaps the first-row has already some css styles declared that you cant override. if you style is really necessary. try adding `!important`, ex:`color:#fff !important;` maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `border-collapse`  to your table rule. See the code below;

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
tr:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(116, 195, 80);
    -webkit-background:linear-gradient(rgb(116, 195, 80), rgb(160, 219, 132));
   border : 1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<table>

   <tr><td>Heading1</td><td>Heading2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>

 </table>
```

Read more about table styling here : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html
and here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

If you're trying to accomplish something like the one on your screenshot, notice that it isn't the `table row` that is `rounded` it is the `column` of that `row`. Notice I `removed` the `table-collapsed` rule set on the table and apply a gradient on the row while applying the `border-radius` on the `TD's` of the table's first row.

If you need to have border on row try the `outline` rule to the table row, although you won't be able to add border-radius to it.

```css
tr:first-child {
   color : #fff;
  background: #a4b357; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a4b357 0%, #75890c 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a4b357 0%,#75890c 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #a4b357 0%,#75890c 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a4b357', endColorstr='#75890c',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-background:linear-gradient(rgb(116, 195, 80), rgb(160, 219, 132));
   
  }


 tr:first-child th{
   border-top-left-radius : 5px;
   border-top-right-radius : 5px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   padding : 10px;

 }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Team Name</th>
     <th>Location</th>
     <th>League Type</th></tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Afterburn - Air Force</td>
     <td>Colorado</td>
     <td>Men's</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here's a jsfiddle so you can play around with it. :) https://jsfiddle.net/9pwr566t/7/

I also updated your html code to follow the proper table structure, see the code below

```css
thead tr {
   color : #fff;
  background: #a4b357; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a4b357 0%, #75890c 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a4b357 0%,#75890c 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #a4b357 0%,#75890c 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a4b357', endColorstr='#75890c',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-background:linear-gradient(rgb(116, 195, 80), rgb(160, 219, 132));
   
  }


thead tr th{
   border-top-left-radius : 5px;
   border-top-right-radius : 5px;
   border: 2px solid darkgreen;
   padding : 10px;

 }

tbody tr {
   background-color : #E4F5D4;
}

tbody tr td {
   padding : 10px;
   color : #333;
}
```

```html
   <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
                <th>Team Name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>League Type</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Afterburn - Air Force</td>
                <td>Colorado</td>
                <td>Men's</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: border-collapse creates a displayable border for the whole row, but unfortunately, it doesn't really match the example (nor does it let me round the border-corners for some reason.

I've been trying to see if I could use any advanced selectors to help me out but...

Comment: based on the screenshot you provided the table row isn't the one styled to have rounded corners it is the table column. I created a jsfiddle that do something like the one on your screenshot, check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/fgdsmphh/

Comment: Hey I actually thought about this and tried to implement it myself... But even with your suggestion, i still can't get a visible border.

Comment: You can add the border on columns when you use the second example I provided. Are you trying or want to add border on row instead of the column? If the latter try adding outline: 2px solid #000; on the row and see if it adds a border on the row

Comment: I'm trying to add borders around the columns. Also... I tried copying and pasting your code out of desperation and it didn't work... I'm so confused at this point. I'm checking to see if there's a bigger issue with my code (any missing semi-colons? anything?)

Comment: Can i see what you have so far? on this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9pwr566t/1/) you can see that I added a red border on the columns

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in the second example in this fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/9pwr566t/4/ )

Comment: see the updated jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9pwr566t/6/) my code works except that you use th inside tr so you need to change the css element tag from tr:first-child td to tr:first-child th :)

Comment: I also updated the answer so you could properly format your table, check the 3rd example I provided you and check how the styling is done properly :)

Comment: Thank you so much I am sorry that this took so long I was just really torn up over this and I guess I got carried away and didn't notice that one selector

Comment: No problem glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `thead` tag for the table heading so that you can simply write css without confusion as,

```
table thead tr {
  background-color: rgb(116, 195, 80);
    -webkit-background:linear-gradient(rgb(116, 195, 80), rgb(160, 219, 132));
}
```

Sample [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/ep43qx40/2/)

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}

table thead tr {
  background-color: rgb(116, 195, 80);
    -webkit-background:linear-gradient(rgb(116, 195, 80), rgb(160, 219, 132));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head1</th>
      <th>Head2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to alter the html5 code for this webpage. Only the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add borders to the first and last children:

```css
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}

table tr:first-child th:last-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```